Do rudras make the demigods cry?
I read this on this site:

There are 11 Rudras also called Ekadash Rudra. They rule in Prana and
Mind of any living thing. As 11 Rudras are present in prana and mind,
so they often manifest when exalted Supreme personalities become
angry:


When they depart from this mortal body, they make us cry (rodayanti),
and because they make us cry, they are called Rudras.'

There was this description of the devatas from Buddha's parinirvana. Here is says:

“Ānanda, there are devatās who perceive space to be earth. Tearing at
their hair, they are weeping. Uplifting their arms, they are weeping.
As if their feet were cut out from under them,45 they fall down and
roll back & forth, crying, ‘All too soon, the Blessed One will totally
unbind! All too soon, the One Well-Gone will totally unbind! All too
soon, the One with Eyes [alternate reading: the Eye] will disappear
from the world!’ Then there are devatās who perceive earth to be
earth. Tearing at their hair, they are weeping. Uplifting their arms,
they are weeping.

Did the rudras make those devatas cry? Do rudras make the demigods cry?

Yes. Rudra means one who makes all the (materially bound) jivas cry including the demigods. https://namahshivaya.net/rudra-cry-makes-us-cry-removes-our-cry/

Let's drop the "Demigod" Abrahamic terminology. Vedic realm has Devas. Some are Cumulative in nature and some are not. Rudra is a Cumulative Divinity with many contradictions. Here is a link that has your quoted reference along with others explaining the nature of Rudra and the concept of Sorrow/Cry.
Here are a Vedic references where Rudra Roared to other Devas:

Wandering Rudra in the heavenly realm (svargaṃ lokaṃ) with a sun-like
luster/brilliance (ādityavarṇaṃ). The Devas who ascended to the
heavenly realm saw and sought Rudra as to who he was (.abruvan: ko
.asīti). I am Rudra (ahaṃ rudro), I am Indra (aham indro), I am the
Āditya (aham indro, aham ādityo), I am divine brilliance the
encompasses entirety ( ahaṃ sarvasyāvayā haraso divyasyeti). The Devas
claimed no offering to Rudra. He Roared fiercely towards them
(rudratvam). The devas realized this and addressed him with due
reverence by calling him Bhava. They said Bhava the entirety is thy
Sarva. Because they said you are all this that revealed Śarva’s
[prowess] as an archer. Because he then became favorable that is
Śiva’s benevolence.
Caraka Katha Āraṇyaka 2.100/101

--Source link--
There are many such references in the Vedas where Rudra roared and took ownership esp with Prajapati.
Still, one thing remains unanswered, What is the user trying to understand? These are divine Vedic concepts. The terminology and translation and its intended meaning very based on the translation.

Whatever you or anyone does is within the confined list of possiblities of this creation (Desha/Kaala). Shiva the ever Auspiciousness is always there, no matter what type of possiblity in creation it may be like war, rape, calamity, starvation or the inverse extreme. The Rudras are all within, if you use these Rudras (mind, breath, ...) as tools and use them either into Yoga and uplift towards consciousness or indulge deeper into ego, sensual pleasure, or pride. Either way the "Eternal Auspiciousness" cares less. Each of us are the rulers of our own Actions and their consequences.

Can you post a reference to the statement - "There are many such references in the Vedas where Rudra roared and took ownership esp with Prajapati."?

@blue_ego the Source Link I shared is a dedicated research portal on Rudra. It has many references including the page called "Birth of Rudra/Gayatri" and "Satarudriya" as well. There are references of Katha Shaka of Yajur Veda of Rudra intemidating other Devas in this portal. I would suggest spending some time on it. Good day.
